# ref.OrderByChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I tried list my data in a live search button but got an error saying:

> OrederByChild is not a function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchSearchResults('');
  }, []);

  const fetchSearchResults = (query) => {
    
    const ref = collection(db, "categories"); 

    ref
      .orderByChild('name') 
      .startAt(query)
      .endAt(query + '\uf8ff') 
      .once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const data = snapshot.val();
          const results = Object.values(data);
          setSearchResults(results);
        } else {
          setSearchResults([]);
        }
      })
```

Comment: If it's "`OrederByChild ` is not a function" It's either that it's a typo of "`orderByChild`" or  `ref` is not being returned as the type you expect

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up both API version and products in your code.

- Firebase has two databases: Firestore and Realtime Database. While both are part of Firebase, they're completely separate and the API for one can't be used on the other.
- Firebase made major changes to it's JavaScript API in SDK version 9 a few years ago, switching from a namespaced API model (where you type `object.method().method()` to a modular API model (where you type `function1(function2(object))`.

In your code you're trying to use the `orderByChild` API (which is specific to the Realtime Database) on a `collection` reference (which is specific to Firestore). That can't work.

You're also mixing modular syntax (`const ref = collection(db, "categories");`), with namespaced syntax (`ref.orderByChild('name')...`). This also can't work.

I recommend starting with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs) for the database that you want to use, and follow the steps on getting started from there.